# Migrate Tables from one one RDS Postgres schema to another within the same DB Instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I have a use case where I am splitting one service into multiple and want to migrate tables (with huge data) from one RDS Postgres schema to another within the same DB Instance with ongoing replication and ~zero downtime, I am exploring AWS DMS service, I can see it is possible to migrate the entire DB, is it possible to migrate only a specific schema and how?

Using alter table query is not an option because I cannot move the table in one shot in production, it needs to happen gradually. An AWS DMS-like solution will fit the use-case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey! Were you able to figure out a solution for it? I am also looking solution for a similar use case.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a table from one schema to another schema, can be done by just [altering](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-altertable.html) the schema:

```
ALTER TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] name
    SET SCHEMA new_schema
```

Comment: this can move the table but for the production use case where I want to gradually turn off the traffic, moving tables in one shot would not work.

Comment: That's not what you asked for: "want to migrate tables (with huge data) from one RDS Postgres schema to another within the same DB Instance with ongoing replication and ~zero downtime". You're now asking for something different. So what is it that you really want?

Comment: The last has the answer for your question, "I can see it is possible to migrate the entire DB, is it possible to migrate only a specific schema and how", the question is wrt AWS DMS. Also updating my question to make it clearer.